# Multiple Countries for Android AutocompleteFilter

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

My app have to provide a Place Autocompleter for Google APIs.
But there should only display locations for selected countries.
For example only addresses in US and in UK.
Here the used code-snipped for the filter:

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
            .setCountry("US")
            .build();
```

Is there any solution to set the method setCountry() to multiple counties?
I have tried .setCountrie("US, UK") ... but this don't work.

any idea?

Comment: do you want to search for only specific multiple country?

Comment: Maybe you can use one AutoCompleteFilter for each country and then combine somehow the results?

Comment: Have you tried using `+` delimiter? Like "US+UK". It works for name maybe it'll work for country as well

Comment: The delimiter not works. Trying to combine the filters even don't work.

Comment: @Navinaut have you found answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
        .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
        .setCountry("my|country:ph|country:sg")
        .build();
```

This works for me. iOS SDK set like this. That's how I know.

Answer (score 1):

A new method `setCountries()` has been added to the SDK.

1. Make sure to update places dependency on gradle to the latest (I'm using 2.2.0 here)

> implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'

2. Use the new method, here is an example using intent:

**Java**

```java
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
                .setCountries(Arrays.asList("FR", "IT"))
                .build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**Kotlin**

```
val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
             AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
            .setCountries(listOf("FR", "IT"))
            .build(this)
startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

*Note:* keep in mind autocomplete results to up to ***five*** countries according to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

this an old question:
but for those who are still not able to get the .setCountries(Arrays.asList("DZ", "US"))
and only getting the .setCountry("US")
make sure to update your place api in the gradle
as 12/26/2020 its version 2.4.0

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String country[] = { "IN", "US","TW"};

FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = 
FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
            .setCountries(country)
            .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
            .setSessionToken(token)
            .setQuery(constraint.toString())
            .build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code.

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
            .setCountry("US")
            .setCountry("UK")
            .build();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it uses the last value passed to `setCountry()` method